# PHP web application, what is the scope of defined constants?

Tags: php

I am working with a PHP web application that was written to run locally (e.g. WAMP or the like), and I am in the process of moving it online. The original author used constants, for example:

```
define('EndDate', 'value');
```

The operation of the program is one thing, but I'm curious as to the lifecycle of PHP constants. If I have two links, with two of the same applications, same user, what will happen with the constants?

For example (Same user, one screen):

```
Click Here for Application Instance 1
Click Here for Application Instance 2
```

If Application Instance 1 has this "EndDate" defined, will it leak over into Instance 2? They are running in Apache 2. I hope to get rid of these fast, but I'm worried about this use case especially, and I can't find any info out there so far.

Edit: Removed reference to $_SESSION because it will confuse my actual question.

Also let me clarify that when I say INSTANCE 2, I really just mean a different subdirectory on the same webserver.

Thank you for your help,
Dan Chase

Comment: as soon as one request is done, the defined constant is gone. It doesn't persist - unless you use a session-var to fill the constant (as you had it before). But maybe I missunderstood the "Application Instance"!?

Comment: You can think of defined constants like global variables which cannot be changed once set _for that execution of PHP_. The constants live in PHP, not Apache. Each time the person clicks, PHP will run, define the constant and do whatever else you want.

Comment: So you're saying through all of the requires(), but like Jeff said once the request is done, it's gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its constrained to the scope of the application itself, everything under index.php

That's if you have two completely separate apps each of the has its own front controller (index.php), then what ever is defined in one app won't affect the other so supposingly you defined a var in your index.php then its constrained to that app.